# a two-sided formula is required for oneway.test

Tags: r

I am getting a strange error saying that a two-sided formula is required for this test.

oneway anova test should be testing one continuous variable with a categorical variable (with more than 1 category).

Apparently there's a conflict with modern dive package? This is strange.

```
oneway.test(v1~v2, data = data)
```

v1 is the continuous 0.0 to 1.0
v2 is categorical with 3 categories 1. free, 2. Partly Free, 3. Not Free

Comment: Could you please include the exact error message?

Comment: Error in oneway.test(happy ~ fh, data = Countries_na) : a two-sided formula is required

Comment: I can't see how this error would occur with the example input. Viewing the source of `oneway.test` shows that it checks to see whether `length(as.character(v1~v2)) != 3`. It should be 3 for your example as it evaluates to: `"~" "v1" "v2"`.

Comment: Try with `stats::oneway.test(v1~v2, data = data)`

Comment: This is in R studio. I think there's some internal issues. I found a work around with just lm and anova(analysis)